# how to increase mouse wheel speed ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 my mouse wheel speed is too slow. But in windows it's o.k.. *pointer movement speed is* o.k. but **wheel speed is to slow**. How can I increase the speed.

I've tried this but still slow....

```
$ sudo apt-get install imwheel
```

Create (if necessary) and edit the config file `~/.imwheelrc` with an editor of your choice (e.g. gedit). Fill in the following for increasing the scroll speed for every Command. NB: This configuration file will apply these new scroll settings to all programs, (including the terminal, which may not be what you want).

```
".*"
None,       Up,     Up,     3
None,       Down,   Down,   3
```

If you want to only apply these settings to Chrome, for instance, use these settings instead:

```
".*-chrome*"
None,       Up,     Up,     3
None,       Down,   Down,   3
```

The 3 is the increase of the scroll. For more specific scroll increases take a look at the manpage

```
$ man imwheel
```

or read the README of the project.

You can start imwheel by typing [`imwheel`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIgJQ.png):